# How would Acronis Snap Deployment work with serial keys for apps?

Tags: installation, license, deployment

Let's assume this scenario:

I have to deploy Windows 10 OS and App X to 100 PCs. For Windows OS, I don't see a problem, since I can just enter the volume license key and be done with it.

However, what do I do when I have 100 serial-keys for App X? Would deployment work? Or is it restricted to volume licenses only?

If it IS possible, how would App X know it receives serial-number 1 instead serial-number 2? I would guess every IP is assigned A SINGLE serial-number?

For that to work though, I assume there has to be some sort of installation procedure to happen. Are there any restrictions? Like App X can't work, because it can't work with Acronis Snap Deployment installation procedure where it's supplied with a single serial-key.

Comment: Have you asked the makers of AppX if they have a license key which will authorise 100 machines? Many apps do have multi-seat keys.

Comment: I'm not there yet, I want to know what to do IF such a situation arises where there is no way but to have single licenses for each PC. How would that then work with ASD?

My problem is, how does the App know it's getting a license/key? Does this not require the App to be able to somehow accept commands via whatever method without the admin being physically at the PC and enter the key?

Comment: ah, then I'm afraid idk & will have to bow out. Wish you luck :)